# Offer coauthorship as a reward?

Tags: discussion, bounty

The rule is that math.se does not allow monetary bounties for questions [[1](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22741/how-should-one-handle-posts-offering-money),[2](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20752/monetizing-se-bounties),[3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25615/offering-actual-money-as-a-bounty),[4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243404/pay-real-money-to-set-bounties-another-method-not-replacing-rep-method),[5](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57850/pay-money-to-so-for-quick-support)]. I think that makes sense.

Would it be reasonable/allowed to promise coauthorship of a paper as a "reward" for answering a question? To be clear, I do *not* mean adding the answerer to a paper that they have nothing to do with. Rather I'm thinking of a situation where the question relates directly to a (potential) paper and the answer is key to that.

More precisely: **Would it be acceptable to add a paragraph to the effect of the following to a math.se question?**

> I need this lemma for the analysis of my algorithm for computing an approximate max-obscurity decomposition of a impotent $n \times n$ matrix in $O(n^2 \cdot 0.935^{\sqrt{\log_2 n}} \cdot \log^{28}(n))$-time. This is an important problem in my subsubfield of numerical colinear algebra.
>
> Since I have been stuck on this lemma for some time and it is essential to the analysis, I think finding a proof would merit coauthorship of the resulting paper.

Comment: If I saw that paragraph in a question, it would set off my crank alarm so strongly that I would not even *consider* touching the question.

Comment: @user296602 Fair enough. It could be worded more subtly, but I don't see it as unreasonable. Someone working in algorithms might need some help with a combinatorial lemma. I have had non-internet collaborations of this form.

Comment: In theory this could be nice, props for asking. Also, basic academic honesty dictates you would acknowledge such help as a matter of course. If the help is relatively major, then coauthorship would be on the table. But the word *fantastic* you used does trigger my crank alarm, too. If you are a graduate student or more advanced, then this would be ok. But if you seek to prove Collatz conjecture with a bit of high school algebra, and think you just need this little bit help here... Shudders.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Downvotes on meta indicate disagreement, not bad question quality.

Comment: @user296602 Thanks. I haven't posted on meta before, so I was wondering if that is the case.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clear that I'm (humorously) talking about some obscure research problem and hopefully make the offer sound more reasonable.

Comment: I would say: do not offer co-authorship in advance.  However, after a solution is posted, then (If you still think it appropriate) ask the poster if you may include him as a co-author in your paper.  But of course the answer could be:"Lang's textbook, page 233", and then you would cite the textbook,  not the person answering here.

Comment: Thomas I think this is a valid question on meta, and glad that you asked it before immediately acting on it.  I think @GEdgar has made a wonderful contribution, and I agree with the suggestion.